# Razor Page validation error with a complex object, TryValidateModel() does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building .Net 5 Razor Pages Web App and have a structure with two objects:

```
public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here are fields from my Razor Page to edit Location objects:

```
<input asp-for="Location.Organization.Id" class="hidden" value="@Model.Location.Organization.Id" />
<input asp-for="Location.Id" class="hidden" value="@Model.Location.Id" />
<input asp-for="Location.Name" class="form-control" value="@Model.Location.Name" />
```

I don't have fields for the Organization object on the page.

In the OnPost() method I fill the Organization object from my Database and try to validate the model again.

```
Location.Organization = await _db.Organizations.FindAsync(Location.Organization.Id);

if (!TryValidateModel(Location, nameof(Location)))
{   
    return Page();
}
```

But it does not work. The Model is still invalid (`ModelState.IsValid != true`)

The Validation Error says `Organization.Name` should be filled.

But all the fields in the Location object are filled correctly. After filling the Organization object, the `Organization.Name` field is also filled with not empty string and should pass the validation.

I am fighting with the problem for hours and have already tried to do it other ways, like `TryValidateModel(Location.Organization)` and so on.

I am looking for a way to do it without placing the `Organization.Name` field in the form. Since I have much more other fields in my real Organization object, I don't want to put they all in the form. I also don't want to ignore validation errors.

I am trying currently to understand how `TryValidateModel()` works, but it is not quite simple to find out from the source code.

Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add `ModelState.Clear` before `TryValidateModel(Location, nameof(Location))`.Here is a demo:

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Location = new Location { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "loc", Organization = new Organization { Id = Guid.NewGuid() } };
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            Location.Organization = new Organization { Id = Location.Organization.Id, Name = "org" };
            ModelState.Clear();
            if (!TryValidateModel(Location, nameof(Location)))
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else {
                var s = ModelState.IsValid;
                return Page();
            }
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: You are right, I have tested it and `TryValidateModel()` works. I've tried it before with `ModelState.Clear()` but thought it does not work, because of empty `ModelState.Keys` list after `TryValidateModel()`. If there is no validation errors after `TryValidateModel()`, then `ModelState.IsValid = true` and `ModelState.Keys` is empty. I thought it just does not work. But if there are errors, then they are listed in Keys and `ModelState` is not valid. Thanks a lot! It's good to know.

Comment: But I would rather want to suppress validation for sub objects. Otherwise I would need to fill in the whole structure with all sub objects. And it sounds not very cool.

Comment: I have created the follow-question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/67370045/2487565

Comment: Btw, cool video! Which tool have you used to capture it?