# How can I set `ValidationVisitor.MaxValidationDepth` = 1 only for one Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I change `ValidationVisitor.MaxValidationDepth` locally for one Razor Page to prevent validation of sub objects?

I don't want to  change it globally with `MvcOptions.MaxValidationDepth` like it is described in the Docs: [Maximum recursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#maximum-recursion)

This is a follow question. Please check my original question to see the object structure here:​

[Razor Page validation error with a complex object, TryValidateModel() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67348699/248756)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start from the `IObjectModelValidator`. The default implementation is internal (`DefaultObjectValidator`) and inherits from `ObjectModelValidator`. The base (and abstract) class requires the derived class to implement only one method called `GetValidationVisitor`. That's one extensibility point for you to modify the `MaxValidationDepth` of the `ValidationVisitor` before it runs. The default implementation `DefaultObjectValidator` just sets the `MaxValidationDepth` to the value obtained from `MvcOptions`. So it's applied globally as you said.

In your custom implementation for `IObjectModelValidator` (of course we let it inherit from `ObjectModelValidator`), you can obtain the `MaxValidationDepth` from the current context instead.

Before executing each page handler, you can set the `MaxValidationDepth` of your choice. To make it standard (used like a cross-cutting concern), we can create an `IAsyncPageFilter` as an attribute that can be applied on any page model class you want.

Here's the implementation code:

```
//the custom IObjectModelValidator (which is much like what from the source code 
//of DefaultObjectValidator)
public class ContextBasedObjectModelValidator : ObjectModelValidator
{
    readonly MvcOptions _mvcOptions;
    public ContextBasedObjectModelValidator(IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider, 
                                            IList<IModelValidatorProvider> validatorProviders,
                                            MvcOptions mvcOptions) : base(modelMetadataProvider, validatorProviders)
    {
        _mvcOptions = mvcOptions;
    }

    public override ValidationVisitor GetValidationVisitor(ActionContext actionContext, 
        IModelValidatorProvider validatorProvider, 
        ValidatorCache validatorCache, 
        IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, 
        ValidationStateDictionary validationState)
    {            
        var visitor = new ValidationVisitor(
            actionContext,
            validatorProvider,
            validatorCache,
            metadataProvider,
            validationState)
        {
            MaxValidationDepth = actionContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature>()?.MaxValidationDepth ?? _mvcOptions.MaxValidationDepth,
            ValidateComplexTypesIfChildValidationFails = _mvcOptions.ValidateComplexTypesIfChildValidationFails,
        };

        return visitor;
    }
}

//we need a class for the custom request feature to hold your context-based MaxValidationDepth
public interface IContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature
{
    int MaxValidationDepth { get; }
}
public class ContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature : IContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature
{
    public ContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature(int maxValidationDepth)
    {
        MaxValidationDepth = maxValidationDepth;
    }
    public int MaxValidationDepth { get; }
}

//here the page filter to help set your context-based MaxValidationDepth
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MaxValidationDepthAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncPageFilter
{
    public MaxValidationDepthAttribute(int maxValidationDepth)
    {
        MaxValidationDepth = maxValidationDepth;
    }
    public int MaxValidationDepth { get; }
    public Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        //set the max validation depth from the predefined value (via the attribute)
        context.HttpContext.Features
               .Set<IContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature>(new ContextBasedMaxValidationDepthFeature(MaxValidationDepth));
        return next();
    }

    public Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Finally we need to register your custom `IObjectModelValidator` inside the `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IObjectModelValidator), sp => {
            var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value;
            var metadataProvider = sp.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();
            return new ContextBasedObjectModelValidator(metadataProvider, options.ModelValidatorProviders, options);
        }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
```

Use it:

```
//suppose you want it to be 1
//for this specific page
[MaxValidationDepth(1)]
public class YourPageModel : PageModel {
     //...
}
```

Comment: I thought it could be done somewhat simpler. But, thanks a lot for the fantastic answer!

Comment: @Tolbxela you're welcome. It's not simpler because the requirement is kind of special and of course not supported by default. It becomes more obvious when you look into the source code (that I mentioned about how & where `MaxValidationDepth` is set). In many cases, only by reading the source code, you will be able to find an answer (by customizing it). It's one strong point of `asp.net core` (easy to read the source code and easy to customize). Once you're familiar with it, you'll see it's not complicated although the code is fairly long :)